# how to read an Excel column with C#

Tags: c#, excel

I try to read an Excel file with my C# application. So far it works fine, I can select a row and read the values:

```
    Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item("Table1");
    Range range = ws.UsedRange;

    Excel.Range currentRangeCells = ws.get_Range("F3", "F" + range.Rows.Count);
    System.Array dataArray = (System.Array)currentRangeCells.Cells.Value2;


    for (int i = 1; i < dataArray.Length; i++)
    {

        if (dataArray == null)
            continue;

        if (dataArray.GetValue(i, 1) == null)
            continue;

        Debug.Write(i.ToString() + ": Value1" + dataArrayValue1.GetValue(i, 1) + "\r\n");
    }
```

Is there any way to get the Cell informations too? I would like to save the value and in which cell the value is or at least in which row the value is.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking - your title implies you are asking how to read a column (Worksheet has a [Columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.columns.aspx) property. But your question is asking about cells and/or rows. Also note that the check for dataArray==null inside the loop is not required - it should be outside the loop otherwise the dataArray.Length check would cause an exception before you get into the loop.

Comment: You need to specify what library you are using e.g. Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application, Aspose.Cells, NPOI. Also, each one of these has plenty of online documentation.

Comment: I'm using  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

Comment: Ok I try to describe it better. If My range would be e.g. A1:C50 and then I loop through the dataArray, I have a list of all values from all cells but not the information which cell (e.g. A3 or B2 or whatever) the value is from. So I would like to be able to create a map. Something like
Key=value
"A2"="Hello"
"B5"="Test"